# Protection against electrostatic paint by draining the charge

Tags: esd, electrostatic

I have a circuit for an automotive sensor aimed for 24V supply. The circuit itself is well tested for EMC requirements including power line transients and EMC immunity. Usually the requirement is for all the terminal pins to be galvanically isolated from the metal housing. We have but a strange requirement from one of our customers that demands the opposite. They subject our sensors to electrostatic painting and it may be - just may be- that some charge gets induced on one of the terminal pins. They want some high resistance conduction path from the pins to the case-housing to provide as a relief valve for the charge to be grounded in such situation. I already have the Y-caps from case-housing to all the lines. I was thinking of some high resistors in parallel to each of these caps as a charge draining path. but then what effect would it have on the galvanic insulation requirement (>10Meg @ 500V)?

Comment: As you state it in your question, the galvanic insulation requirement (>10Meg @ 500V) is not satisfied when placing a high resistance conduction path from the pins to the case-housing if this "high resistance conduction path" exceeds 10 Meg. Quite obvious... so, I wonder if you are asking *that*. Can you please specify/elaborate your question?

Comment: Should this protection prevent **current entering** the pins or should it prevent a too high voltage on the pins (and a small discharge current into the sensor allowed?)

Comment: Just provide the painter with plugs for each connector that have 1k resistors to ground. Plug them in, paint, pull them off, bake.

Comment: @Huisman: It cannot be 10 Megs, thats the problem. The customer wants to avoid high charge from building up so they want the charge to leak somehow via this path. How they test this is, the apply a DC supply between each pin and the case one by one. Then they increase the DC voltage slowly from 0 to 200VDC. They want to see a stable DC current of at least 250uA before they reach 200VDC. That brings us to about 500 to 800K. I was thinking about some TVS in series with this resistor .... May be.. I dont know.

Comment: (1) I think you should get clear what they really want. **Why** do they want to avoid high charge from building up? Or do they want to avoid high **voltage** from building up? Or should the bleeding current be 250 uA or larger? (2) I wonder if their test simulates the functionality they want: a DC source from 0V to 200V =/= ESD pulse. (3) If they really *"want to see a stable DC current of at least 250uA before they reach 200VDC"*, then it is impossble to have a galvanic isolation that is 250uA @ 200VDC and less than 50 uA @ 500V.

Comment: @Huisman... Exactly, thats why were also confused.... So we clarified further and in the review they told us that isolation requirement (for them) is 10Megs @ 48V. So now I am using a 60V TVS in series with a 300K resistor across the Y Cap and that seems to have solved the problem. You are right it is not exactly the test that simulates ESP painting but thats how they test it according to their specs. Thanks for your help and time :).

Comment: Nice you got some clarifications. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like placing a TVS in series with a suiatble high value resistor  across the CASE (Y) capacitor helps to leak this current out of the system. It also seems that I did not need to place this series combi across each Y Cap but only across the GND to CASE Y cap because all other terminals have some path to the GND (VCC and CAN lines via TVSs for example.)